# nvidia-smi: command not found on Ubuntu 16

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I installed CUDA with

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I then tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

After typing `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`, I see `nvidia-375` and `nvidia-378`

However, I then tried `nvidia-smi` and got

> WARNING:root:could not open file
> '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/osmosa-ubuntu-audio-recorder-xenial.list'
>
> nvidia-smi: command not found

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: did you try running `sudo apt update` after running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and before running `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`?

Comment: I did run `sudo apt update`. I don't remember if it was before `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Comment: please restart your Ubuntu machine, and check if it solve the problem

Comment: I did restart, and I still get the same error with `nvidia-smi`