# How can I find out which GPU is being used in my ubuntu16.04 LTS?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I used **$ sudo lshw -C display** which dispalayed the following :

***-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:43 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

*-display UNCLAIMED

```
   description: 3D controller
   product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff**
```

But when I am using **$ nvidia-smi**, it is showing **nvidia-smi: command not found**

How to fix this? I think may be NVIDIA drivers are not installed properly. WHat can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your exact question is not clear. Do you want to know the GPU name is being used or you want to fix NVIDIA driver issue?

Comment: Both actually. I couldn't know which GPU is being used. But as nvidia-smi is not working, I guess i need to fix the NVIDIA driver. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For check use this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card    and for the driver error use this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/902636/nvidia-smi-command-not-found-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On terminal:

```
lspci -v |egrep "VGA|Display"
```

The one that has "[VGA Controller]" at the end is the one used by system.