# Cannot install nvidia-smi - 600x600 only monitor res

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I tried all I knew until now but there's no way to execute `nvidia-smi`.

This is my GPU:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C81sv00001043sd0000203Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

```
nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I have installed:

```
$ apt search nvidia-driver
nvidia-driver-440/unknown,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
  NVIDIA driver metapackage
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440/unknown,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Plus (and this is really awful) I have just the option of to set the screen at 800x600  :(

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using? And how did you install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 19.10, I installed the drivers with apt and manually. 
Now after blacklisted the nvidia nouveau, I recovered the screen, but nothing about nvidia-smi.

Comment: Thats strange. If you install the nvidia driver by via "Software& Update" nouveau will be blacklisted in the process. Concerning your nvidia-smi problem - it has been discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902636/nvidia-smi-command-not-found-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.